# Prevent Bash script overflowing printed text when at console edge

Tags: bash, shell

If my console window has width of 30, and I print the following line:

```
printf "This is exactly forty characters printed!"
```

It will display as such:

```
This is exactly forty character
s printed!
```

Whereas I would like to avoid the drop onto a new line, and rather let the last 10 characters 'be hidden' beyond the terminal edge.

Is this possible with a Bash script?

Comment: [Terminal long line wrapping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529377/terminal-long-line-wrapping) is likely a good answer to start with.

Comment: Your question is not bash-related. While bash, if the terminal settings allow it, knows the size of your terminal (do a `echo $COLUMNS`), it has no control over the output from their child processes. Either you modify your programs, so that they exhibit the desired behaviour, or - more realistically - you instruct your terminal application to take care of this.